# Twitter Integration follower list ids

Tags: android, api, twitter

I have created a twitter login in integration successfully in the app. I'm able to obtain user id and user name. But I'm trying to obtain a user's follower list using the twitter api but my code is not working. Is there some further authentication needed or whats going wrong? When I put another json link for the url, it works fine.

```
 public class TwitterFragment extends Fragment {

TextView txtJson;
ProgressDialog pd;


Fragment fragment;

private TwitterLoginButton twitterLoginButton;

private TextView userDetailsLabel;


//twitter auth client required for custom login
private TwitterAuthClient client;

Callback<TwitterSession> callback;

private Button mSendData;


ViewGroup rootView;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //returning our layout file


    TwitterConfig config = new TwitterConfig.Builder(getActivity())
            .logger(new DefaultLogger(Log.DEBUG))//enable logging when app is in debug mode
            .twitterAuthConfig(new TwitterAuthConfig(getResources().getString(R.string.com_twitter_sdk_android_CONSUMER_KEY), getResources().getString(R.string.com_twitter_sdk_android_CONSUMER_SECRET)))
            .debug(true)//enable debug mode
            .build();
    Twitter.initialize(config);

    rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_twitter, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);

    fragment= null;



    //initialize twitter auth client

    client = new TwitterAuthClient();


    //find the id of views
    twitterLoginButton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.default_twitter_login_button);
    txtJson=(TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
    userDetailsLabel = rootView.findViewById(R.id.user_details_label);

    //NOTE : calling default twitter login in OnCreate/OnResume to initialize twitter callback
    defaultLoginTwitter();


    //change R.layout.yourlayoutfilename for each of your fragments
    return rootView;
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Pass the activity result to the twitterAuthClient.
    if (client != null)
        client.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Pass the activity result to the login button.
    twitterLoginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}



/**
 * @return the current {@link com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback}
 */
public Callback<TwitterSession> getCallback() {
    return callback;
}


public void defaultLoginTwitter() {
    //check if user is already authenticated or not


    //if user is not authenticated start authenticating
    twitterLoginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {

        @Override
        public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
            getTwitterSession();


            // Do something with result, which provides a TwitterSession for making API calls
            TwitterSession twitterSession = result.data;

            //call fetch email only when permission is granted
            fetchTwitterEmail(twitterSession);

        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            // Do something on failure
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed to authenticate. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

/**
 * Sets the {@link com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback} to invoke when login completes.
 *
 * @param callback The callback interface to invoke when login completes.
 * @throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException if callback is null.
 */
public void setCallback(Callback<TwitterSession> callback) {
    if (callback == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Callback cannot be null");
    }
    this.callback = callback;
}

/**
 * Before using this feature, ensure that “Request email addresses from users” is checked for your Twitter app.
 *
 * @param twitterSession user logged in twitter session
 */
public void fetchTwitterEmail(final TwitterSession twitterSession) {
    client.requestEmail(twitterSession, new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<String> result) {
            new JsonTask().execute("GET https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=andypiper&count=5000\n" );

            //here it will give u only email and rest of other information u can get from TwitterSession
            userDetailsLabel.setText("User Id : " + twitterSession.getUserId() + "\nUser Name : " + twitterSession.getUserName() + "\nEmail Id : " + result.data);

            FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

            DatabaseReference myRef2= database.getReference("Social media:");
            myRef2.push().setValue("Twitter");

            DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("User Id");
            myRef.push().setValue(twitterSession.getUserId());

            DatabaseReference myRef1 = database.getReference("User Name");
            myRef1.push().setValue(twitterSession.getUserName());

        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed to authenticate. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}


/**
 * get authenticates user session
 *
 * @return twitter session
 */
private TwitterSession getTwitterSession() {
    TwitterSession session = TwitterCore.getInstance().getSessionManager().getActiveSession();

    //NOTE : if you want to get token and secret too use uncomment the below code
    TwitterAuthToken authToken = session.getAuthToken();
    String token = authToken.token;
    String secret = authToken.secret;

    return session;
}








@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
    getActivity().setTitle("Education and career");
}


class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pd.setMessage("Please wait");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

            connection.connect();


            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line+"\n");
                Log.d("Response: ", "> " + line);   //here u ll get whole response...... :-)

            }

            return buffer.toString();


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (pd.isShowing()){
            pd.dismiss();
        }
        txtJson.setText(result);
    }

}

}
```